# AWS - ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I just deployed a lambda using serverless but I'm not allowed to access the s3 bucket I want to. Is there anything in this code that is obviously broken?

```
service: handler
frameworkVersion: '2'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221
  iam:
    role:
      statements:
        - Effect: 'Allow'
          Action:
            - 's3:GetObject'
            - 's3:PutObject'
          Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket"
plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements

package:
  exclude:
    - node_modules/**
functions:
  login:
    handler: handler.login
    events:
     - httpApi:
          path: /login
          method: post
```

And here's the function trying to access s3

```
def check_s3(user):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    obj = s3.get_object(Bucket="my_bucket", Key=user)
    data = json.loads(obj['Body'].read())
    return data
```

Error I'm getting:

```
[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 11, in login
    d = check_s3(username)
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 34, in check_s3
    obj = s3.get_object(Bucket="my_bucket", Key=user)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 386, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 705, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
```

Comment: Have you verified that the object you are trying to get exists? S3 will return access denied when there isn't an object with the specified key. Double-check the bucket and key to be certain.

Answer (score 8):

The problem was that the file I tried to fetch did not exist

Comment: Actually helpful. For me had wrong bucket name in config. This answer got me there faster.

Answer (score 5):

Your resource needs to be `"arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*"` because you get an object, not the bucket itself. [S3 Permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazons3.html)

Comment: Thanks but I'm still getting the same error. Could it be the buckets permissions? I have pretty standard permissions I believe. No outside access

Comment: Unless you have an explicit deny on the bucket policy it shouldn't matter. Did you give it a little time from when you updated the policy to when you ran the code again? Sometimes there is a delay, especially if it's not in us-east-1. Beyond that you'd need to see if there are any permission boundaries or SCPs that are restricting access. The above policy should be enough to just get an object. You might try adding the error message to your question.

Comment: Tried it again now and still doesn't work unfortunately. Added both s3:::my_bucket and s3:::my_bucket/* but still no access

Comment: If you can include the actual error message (you can mask the bucket name and object name) that would be helpful. The error often gives some more information. The bottom line is that you have your permissions wrong somewhere.

Comment: Sure, I have added the error in the OP now. Unfortunately it doesn't say much

Comment: I think the issue was that the file didn't exist. Weird error in that case

Comment: I believe it's intentional. Either way, the permission to add `/*` to the end of the resource is necessary.

Comment: Not a great practice, but this answer led me to allow all resources `resources=["*"]`, instead of just the bucket arn (within CDK) in my hobby project and thus allowed me to move fast in my free time

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR** make sure your role can do `s3:ListBucket`

I want to share an answer for this because it was a pain for our team because we knew that the server had `s3:GetObject` but kept getting the error above. Sometimes you will get this error if the object does not exist. I.e. you get the following error:

> ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied

Instead of a more meaningful error like a `s3_client.exceptions.NoSuchKey`. The reason can be found in the [boto3 docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object):

[image]